# fill-paragraph in programming

Tags: formatting, fill-paragraph, programming

Is it possible, or does some function exists, to get the equivalent of the `alt-q` command, but in programming?

Suppose I've just written this in python:

```
group_parser.add_argument('-n',nargs=1, default=5,
help='specifies how many missing entries in a row are allowed before the whole row gets omitted.')
```

The following is a rather long line. Is it possible to have some sort of automation for getting the following output?

```
parser.add_argument('-n',nargs=1, default=5, 
                    help='specifies how many ' +
                    'missing entries in a row ' +
                    'are allowed before the whole row gets ' +
                    'omitted.')
```

In other words, a function that detects long input strings, and splits them up across multiple lines.

Comment: Obviously that kind of behaviour would be specific to each individual programming language. As a complete tangent, you might find the [Keep Left](http://perl.find-info.ru/perl/028/perlbp-chp-2-sect-16.html) formatting style an improvement when breaking lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [multi-line](https://github.com/IvanMalison/multi-line). Out of the box it works sanely for many languages. You can cycle through many different indentation strategies.